# Update Mono Error 99

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, compiler-errors, monodevelop

After a last update of monotouch (Monotouch 5.4.1) Monodevelop 3.0.4.6.

All builds fails with message " mtouch exited with code 99".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem.
I have delete monotouch and reinstall for reactivate key.